# Create, write to and open a text file from SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I am displaying a SaveFileDialog and when OK is clicked I am creating new file, writing some default content to it and then attempting to Open it via the OpenFile() method of the SaveFileDialog. However, the moment I call OpenFile() the content of the file are deleted.

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml";
saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    // First Event Creates file and writes default content to it - works ok 
    NewFileCreated( this, new FileCreatedEventArgs() { Template = Template.BBMF, FilePath = saveFileDialog.FileName } );
    // Second Event clears file content as soon as saveFileDialog.OpenFile() called
    FileLoaded( this, new FileLoadedEventArgs() { FileStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile() } );
}
```

Can someone explain why this happens and what I need to be doing to successfully Open the newly created file?

Comment: Please provide the code of the events, that's where something is going wrong probably.

Comment: Why are you using events for this flow? They will be async, you cannot guarantee the order of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN, SaveFileDialog.OpenFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.openfile.aspx)

> **Caution**
>
> For security purposes, this method creates a new file with the
>   selected name and opens it with read/write permissions. This can cause
>   unintentional loss of data if you select an existing file to save to.
>   To save data to an existing file while retaining existing data, use
>   the File class to open the file using the file name returned in the
>   FileName property.

Comment: Yes, this is what i did. Created the File in the NewFileCreated event and then opened it using the File Class in the FileLoaded event

Comment: So, If you want to open the file without destroying the existing contents you need to open it via the FileStream class and pass in  FileMode.Append to the appropriate ctor.